# No ionic back button visable following view change via $state.go ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have 2 views as follows

```
    .state('tab.matches', {
    url: '/matches',
    views: {
      'tab-matches': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/bant-tab-matches.html',
        controller: 'MatchesCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
    .state('tab.matches-detail', {
    url: '/matches/:matchId/:userId/:userName',
    views: {
      'tab-matches': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/bant-tab-matches-detail.html',
        controller: 'MatchesDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

I have a button on a different view which on click calls a function in the controller as follows:

```
$scope.messageUser = function (postInfo) {

$state.go('tab.matches-detail', { matchId: var1, userId: var2, userName: var3 });

}
```

This redirects to the tab.matches-detail view as expected but a back button is not present. I would like the back button to redirect back to the parent view being `tab.matches`, or the view I originally redirected from. If I navigate from `tab.matches` to `tab.matches-detail` (when I have not redirected by `$state.go`) the back button is present. I however am going direct to `tab.matches-detail` when `$state.go` is called. As such I can no longer access `tab.matches` as if I click on another tab and then return to `tab.matches` it displays `tab.matches-detail` with no way to access the parent state of `tab.matches`. I can't figure out how to get the back button to display. I need this to be controlled from the controller rather than a href in the view as I need to call similar functionality from an Actionsheet where the logic is all controller side.

Apologies for the rather verbose explanation but I want to be clear on the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Anthony

Comment: Make a CodePen with your example, or at least add HTML too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I set the back button in the view as not visible by setting `hide-back-button="true"` in the `<ion-view>` tag, then added a button for the header as follows:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left"  class="button-clear customButton">
  <div class = "buttonMatchesInner" ng-click="matchesGoBack()">        
    <i class="ion-chevron-left matchLeftIcon"></i>
  </div>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

With the click event calling:

```
    $scope.matchesGoBack = function() {
        $state.go('tab.matches');
    }
```